# SQL Server Management Studio 2005 - Set Default Encoding

Tags: encoding, sql-management-studio

Is anybody aware of a way to set the default encoding when saving a file to in SQL Server Management Studio to be ANSI instead of Unicode?  Our source control system/diff tools barf when it runs across a Unicode file format.

I've googled a possible solution for this; but all I've found are examples to select the encoding when doing a "Save As..."; which works fine; but needs to be done every time I launch the program.

Is there a registry setting somewhere I could set?  Has anybody else run into this and found a solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature has been requested for the past 4 years by dozens of people, however, this still hasn't been implemented that I can see.

Comment: It's a 7 year-old feature request as of this comment. Please vote here: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/336750/need-a-way-to-set-the-default-encoding-for-query-files-in-smss

Answer (score 0):

I believe it may be possible to do this. I wanted the reverse situation  - files always saved in Unicode rather than ANSI - and I found a Registry setting that enabled me to do that.
The Registry Key is HKEY_USERS\\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\\Tools\Shell\General and the REG_DWORD value is SaveDocsAsUnicodeInDataLoss which was set to 0. I changed it to 1 and the default encoding when saving files switched from ANSI to Unicode.

I infer from that that setting the value to 0 defaults to ANSI.

To change the setting for any future users, change the value in the HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\\Tools\Shell\General key.

Comment: Setting this to 0 does NOT change encoding to ANSI

Answer (score -4):

ANSI is not a good default unless absolutely necessary. UTF-8 is much, much better. UTF-8 is generally compatible with ANSI. (UTF-8 *without signature* is compatible, and is good. UTF-8 *with signature* is a non-compatible (and bad) alternative to UTF-8 without signature. The only purpose to add the signature is make it incompatible to ANSI!) But any Unicode format supports international characters, which is normally *very good*. ANSI has very (very) limited international character support. The world should transition to UTF-8 (without signature). Apparently HTML5 agrees. Horay! Finally a smart character encoding standard.

Comment: -1 This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This may be more appropriate as a comment to the question, instead of an answer